# The Sacrament of the Present Moment?

Tags: spirituality

What did Jean-Pierre De Caussade mean in "God Living in Souls and Souls Living in God?" This is chapter 2: "How to Arrive at the State of Self-Surrender and How to Act Before Reaching It."

Comment: How is this a question about 'Christianity' ? Without the question providing some content, it is impossible to answer the question without specialist knowledge.

Comment: I wasn't sure where this question "fit." The original title was Self-Abandonment to Divine Providence. I'm open for suggestions as to its appropriate placing.

Comment: @edh, because this is a Q&A site, not just a discussion forum, you should phrase your question in the form of a question.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  When doing Google search on the book containing Jean-Pierre's writings [For God's Greater Glory: Gems of Jesuit Spirituality](https://books.google.ca/books?id=f5TZedpYa5MC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), the topic of self-abandonment is covered in [The Fire of Divine Love](https://books.google.ca/books?id=f5TZedpYa5MC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q&f=false) while the section title "God Living in Souls..." is in chapter 2 of [The Sacrament of the Present Moment](https://books.google.ca/books?id=f5TZedpYa5MC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q&f=false).